# Fetch api get call to PHP endpoint that returns JSON object fails but regular XHR works?

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I have a PHP endpoint that returns a JSON-object (maybe that is not what this is?)

```
{"my_array":["a","b","c","d"]}
```

That's what you see when you view that page. It's created using

```
$array = [];
$array['my_array'] = ["a","b","c","d"];
echo json_encode($array);
```

When I use a regular XHR call from MDN

```
// get XHR from MDN
function getAjax(url, success) {
    var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState>3 && xhr.status==200) success(xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.send();
    return xhr;
}
```

I can iterate over it using this post-call function:

```
getAjax('get-users.php', logOutput);

function logOutput(response) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(response));
    // returns: {"my_array":["a","b","c","d"]}
}
```

When I try to do this with fetch, it doesn't work.

```
fetch('get-users.php')
    .then((res) => {
        return res.json(); // also tried res.text();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

I'm not sure if the way I'm creating the output from PHP is wrong, or if my Fetch is wrong.

Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSjEq.png) of the code/console.log

Edit: I wanted to point out it's not a url/target problem, for the sake of site anonymity I whited out some parts of the link.

Comment: Did you try `res.body` or anything like that? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

Comment: @BrianKung No I have not. I tried .json() and .text() that sounds like it will work then I would use regular JSON.parse() I think, let me check. Thanks

Comment: Try add  `header('Content-Type: application/json');` in your PHP

Comment: @BrianKung I tried it I don't get an error but see readableStream this time. I'll try what Guillermo suggested with adding the header. So far not working. I'm thinking my data output isn't formatted right for Fetch or not reading it right.

Comment: I think it is my endpoint data formatting/headers. I tried the code here form css-tricks (tried this from another site as well) but with a known endpoint and it works as expected. https://css-tricks.com/using-fetch/

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and could not reproduce the problem: https://i.imgur.com/dgYlJxM.png

Comment: @Quentin what is in your get-users.php just echoing out that array/no headers? I was also told to check cors. I'm going to look at this again when I get the time/free from work. Thanks for your help

Comment: @subalublub — `<?php` followed by a copy/paste of your three lines of PHP.

Comment: @subalublub — CORS won't help. You have a relative URL. You are not making a cross-origin request. (If CORS would help then you would get a big error message in your browser's Developer Tools' Console).

Comment: @Quentin yeah that's what I thought as well about CORs. I was also told to check the response in console. Anyway I'll take a closer look at it. Good to know that it works as expected.